# Diff Eq. after Real Analysis resources

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, self-learning

I am in the odd position of having learned real analysis, linear algebra, and multivariable calc before having touched differential equations beyond simple applications. Given this, are there resources for learning diff. eq. that would be more useful for me than someone who had not yet done analysis?

Comment: I might suggest Apostol's *Calculus*, Vol. 2, Chapters 6 and 7 to begin with, or, if you don't mind reading French, Chapters 4 and 5 in Volume 4 of *Cours de mathématiques spéciales* by Ramis, Odoux and Deschamps.  Pontryagin and Arnold both have books called *Ordinary Differential Equations*, translated from Russian and intended for students who have a background similar to yours. Neither of these has a heavy focus on computational aspects, which they assume have been discussed previously.

Comment: Don't know any French, but will try the other two.

Comment: I mentioned three other books, one by each of Apostol, Pontryagin and Arnold.